# Gradle multi-project build

Tags: spring, gradle, build.gradle

I have the following project structure:

```
my-project
 +my-project-data
 +my-project-service
 +my-project-example
```

Where each of these my-project-data, my-project-service, my-project-examples are defined as sub project to my-project in settings.gradle file. Of course, my-project-services has a dependency to my-project-data. And my-project-examples has a dependencies to my-project-data and my-project service.

In the project my-project-examples I want to have some class with main method and make some queries to DB (Assume that main class is in package com.project.main). Moreover I want to execute this in command line:

```
java -jar my-project.jar
```

But to do this I have to set Main-Class attribute. Where do I have to do this in root project build.gradle or somewhere else and what have to be the value of attribute?

Comment: http://gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/userguide_single.html#application_plugin

Comment: What do I need from here?

Comment: He's saying that the application plugin is used to define a class to be run from Gradle. You'd likely use that plugin in your "examples" subproject.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the application plug-in which provides exactly what you need.

Add the following to your example's project build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'application'
mainClassName = "com.company.package.YourClassWithMain"
```

Then, simply run the sample by executing 'gradle run' (or using gradle wrapper) under the example project directory.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I also found this. Now if I'm in the root project folder and I execute gradle build command it doesn't package the jar. In the case of non-multi project build when you execute gradle build command you gradle creates folder build and in which folder there is subfolder libs and here is the jar. But now I do not have such one.

Any ideas?

Comment: I will give you some more detail about this.  I want to write something like this in command line:

java -jar my-project.jar db.username=my_username db.password=my_pass

Comment: Regarding your first comment, this is weird since it should not affect the creation of the jar. Can you please share some code?
Regarding your second comment: this is pure java and not related to Gradle. Just make sure that your main method signature receives arguments (public static void main(String[] args))