# Is it possible to build and run Gradle project A as a part of build scenario of project B?

Tags: java, gradle, code-generation, build-automation, gradle-plugin

### Hierarchy of projects in my Gradle setup

| Project name | Depends on | Description |
| --- | --- | --- |
| **engine** | Different 3rd party libraries, not depends on local projects | A game engine I'm working on |
| **game** | **:engine** | Main logic of the game |
| **generator** | **:game** | Utility code which runs on top of game's codebase and generates extra Java sources based on classes / methods it can find on the classpath. This generated code is being used by the **:engine** |
| **android**, **desktop**, **ios** | **:game** | Platform-specific code, not related to the question |

It looks like like this in build.gradle (simplified):

```
project(":engine") {
    dependencies {
        // Some 3rd party dependencies
    }
}

project(":game") {
    dependencies {
        api project(":engine")
    }
}

project(":generator") {
    dependencies {
        api project(":game")
    }
}

project(":android") {
    dependencies {
        api project(":game")
    }
}
```

### The difficult part

The **:engine** contains an implementation of a Lua interpreter and needs quite a lot of procedurally generated code which is based on a data which, on its turn, is only available in the runtime of the **:game** project (or any other project which has **:game** in its classpath).

The **:engine** is meant to be a standalone foundation for the other projects and, ideally, should not even know the name of any project which uses it as a dependency - for example, it should be possible to make two separate projects with a game logic (say, **:game** and **:othergame**).

But **:engine** needs a generated code which can only be generated in the runtime of **:game** and it makes (some sort) of a circullar loop of dependencies which I've not managed to resolve with my poor knowledge of Gradle.

### What is a :generator

It is a regular Java project with a simple `main(String[] args)` entry point. It depends on **:game** which makes it able to scan for classes that exist in both **:engine** and **:game** projects.

It scans classes on the classpath with Reflection, generates new Java source code based on lists of classes / methods of **:engine** & **:game** and writes it into source path of the **:game** project under its specific package path. Next time anything which depends on the **:game** is being run, it has newly generated code on its classpath.

**:engine**'s Lua interpreter simply searches for the generated code using `Class.forName()` so there are no hardcoded imports on the generated code inside of the **:engine**.

*Note A: generated code heavily depends on classes of :engine / :game and uses them in its import statements*

*Note B: when something is being changed in code of the :game, usually I need to delete all of the generated code (part of which becomes broken and won't compile) to be able to run :generator again - probably it would be better to make it a .jar library to avoid errors in IDE / at build time, so it would be even better to create .jar with that generated code*

### Current approach

I do this each time I need to run the game during development:

1. Make changes to **:game** (edit game's logic)
2. *(If there are errors in the previously generated code)* Delete previously generated code
3. (Build and) Run **:generator** as a regular Java console app
4. Run **:desktop** (which simply starts the **:engine**)

This approach has multiple issues, and I hope someone with good knowledge of Gradle can give me a couple of suggestions:

- **:generator** depends on **:game** but, technically, it is a part of an engine and should not know the name of the game's project. I thought of making another project called **:game-generator** which depends on both **:generator** & **:game** and removing **:game** from **:generator**'s dependencies but have not tried it yet because have doubts it will work (actually, was focused on another issue listed below)
- It is not possible to make **:engine** and **:generator** standalone projects because **:generator** has hard-coded dependency on **:game**, and **:engine** can not exist without that generated code (and that's the main issue I'm focusing on right now)
- Running the game requires too many actions and it feels like all of them can be a simple Gradle task / some kind of plugin which is being executed as a part of a regular build procedure

### Failed attempt

I've tried to make a custom plugin for Gradle.

The idea was to apply it in game's project, send in some configurations and run it before any of the game's code is being compiled. But:

- Generator's code can not be run as a part of Gradle, because it needs runtime class info of the game
- Somehow I've not managed to access :generator project and its tasks from the plugin which is applied to :game - is it even possible?
- As a last resort, there's still an idea to write a custom script (for example, in Python) and execute it by means of Gradle at the beginning of the build stage. The script should run `gradle generator:run` (and probably do some other stuff) but I doubt it would run while Gradle is already busy / will need to start a separate Gradle daemon

Thank you for any suggestions.

Comment: Try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28698670/gradle-multi-project-build

Comment: Thanks for the link but that's not what I need.

Comment: Uh oh, 10 minutes till bounty ends. Guess I'll have to rewrite the whole thing into Gradle plugin with ASM then